# How to get just filename from minio (mc) ls

Tags: regex, filenames, ls, minio

I need to retrieve the filename for a bash script. I thought `mc ls` could do all that ls can do, but I seem to be mistaken. So now I'm struggling with [regex](https://regex101.com/r/zNsK85/1).

When I do `mc ls minio/bucket1/`, I'll get:

```
[2021-05-14 11:15:18 CEST]     0B files1/
[2021-05-14 11:15:18 CEST]     0B files2/
[2021-05-14 11:15:19 CEST]     0B file1.ext
[2021-05-14 11:15:18 CEST]     0B file2.ext
```

How can I extract just the filename in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the following `sed` command after your `mc ls` command:

```sh
sed -n 's/^\[[^][]*][[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]\(.*\.gpkg\)$/\1/p'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/FQFnIt).

*Details*:

- `-n` - suppresses the default line output
- `s` - substitution command
- `^\[[^][]*][[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*\(.*\.gpkg\)$` - a regex that matches

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\[[^][]*]` - a substring between `[` and `]` with no square brackets inside
  - `[[:blank:]]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace
  - `[^[:blank:]]*` - zero or more non-horizontal whitespace chars
  - `[[:blank:]]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace
  - `\(.*\.gpkg\)` - Group 1: any text and then `.gpkg`
  - `$` - end of string
- `\1` - replaces the match with Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

mc support json output format , you may do as well something like:

```
./mc ls myminio/bucket1 --json | jq ".key"
"files1/"
"files2/"
"file1.ext"
"file2.ext"
```